# How to use HTML video tag and not receive active x warnings

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video, html5-video

I am creating a html page that will be distributed and run locally.  It has a video which is supposed to play on the page.  When I run the page though, I receive an error saying Internet Explorer restricted this webpage from running scripts or ActiveX controls.

This will happen to the end users also.  What can I do to allow the video to play right away so the warning box does not have to be allowed.

The current code I am using is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0024)http://www.abc-defg.com/ -->
<html> 
    <body>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <video id="video1" width="715" autoplay="autoplay">
                <source src="images\abc Movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I have the abc-defg is the same length as the company name

Comment: [*Mark of the Web*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628(v=vs.85).aspx) should resolve this.

Comment: I tried the mark of web, but it did not help

Comment: Can you please share a full example of what you have tried, removing all non-essential code?

Comment: @Sampson I have updated the code

Comment: Please show the *actual* code (copy, and paste it). Remove all non-essential elements, reducing the `<body>` to nothing more than the `<video>` element.

Comment: I have edited it to include more.  See info under code about web address

Comment: Eric, how do you plan on distributing your HTML to be ran locally?

Comment: It will be on a documentation CD that comes with the product.

Comment: See *A Word about CDs* on [*Understanding Local Machine Zone Lockdown*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/23/understanding-local-machine-zone-lockdown-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/expression/en-US/2536624e-7e66-4a56-a4c5-41d64cf01b0a/html5-video-internet-explorer-restricted-this-webpage-from-running-scripts-or-activex-controls?forum=web), the answer is no.  This is an artifact of loading locally. You'll be fine when you put this on a live web environment.  Objects loaded locally are treated differently,from a security standpoint, than hosted objects, so you can expect a completely different scenario when you have this video hosted on a remote web host.